# Very small sized ubuntu distro

Tags: software-recommendation, ubuntu-minimal

I want to create a very small sized ubuntu VM, preferably under 1 GB (500 to 700 MB). What is the way to create the smallest distro?

I tried minimal ubuntu but after installing it was also about 1.5 GB.

Comment: No. Use an alternate smaller distro

Comment: So it is not possible with ubuntu? Any other debian based distro that you recommend?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you trying to achieve... I have used [**Damn Small Linux**](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org) which should do the job...

Comment: @AbubakarSiddique There's no Debian based distro that will take up that small a space requirement.  You'll consume that 1GB extremely fast with updates, so you will really need a completely different type of distro for that (Damn Small Linux for example may work, but that's not Ubuntu or Debian based)

Comment: @AzkerM lol, stating the same distro I said xD

Comment: I suggest tinycore for something that small

Comment: @ThomasW. - we're always on the same boat :D

Answer (score 3):

To put it simply, there's no Ubuntu or Debian based distro that will fit the size requirements you're stating.  Not even headless.

Your closest bet is [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) which is a very TINY linux distro.  However, it is not Ubuntu nor Debian based, to my knowledge.

If your intent is to have Ubuntu or Debian, have your VM provision 10GB max for the virtual disk, and let it expand in size as needed - this will give it ample 'space' from the Linux point of view, but it will take at most 10GB + amount of vRAM you assign when you save the system.

Answer (score 0):

Try with debían netinstaller the image is reallly small and you can select the minimal packages, then you can add exactly what you need with

```
apt-get
```

Regards.

Comment: I would actually recommend using Ubuntu Server install or something similar, as Debian (although a base for ubuntu) doesn't share enough to work exactly the same aside from basic commands and fuctionality.

Comment: This still pulls down a gig or more of software - net installer is great for a small install ISO but the OP means "installed size" not the installer's physical size.

Comment: Did you try with the expert mode and selecting only basic packages groups?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a mini distro, some of these can run in live mode, where disk space isn't so much an issue.  [Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org) has Ubuntu binary compatible builds.  But it's not Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

U can check them out in this website "distrowatch.com".
You can create a very small sized distro just by removing all things which you think you don't need, while you do have that option while you were installing that kernel.

Comment: While this technically answers the question, it does not truly answer the question nor does it provide helpful pointers to how to proceed.